# enable/disable button with tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I want to enable/disable button when there is text in tinymce. When there is enable button, when there isnt disable button. I try it like this:

```
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode: "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector: "mceEditor"
    });

    $('#btnGeneratePDFMailFormSubmitter').attr('disabled', 'disabled')

    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    var hallo = $('#GeneratePDFMailFormSubmitter').val();
    if ($.trim(hallo.val) != '') {
        alert(hallo);
        $('#btnGeneratePDFMailFormSubmitter').removeAttr('disabled');//  .attr("disabled", true);
    }
    else
        alert(hallo);
    $('#btnGeneratePDFMailFormSubmitter').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //.attr("disabled", false);
```

But the button is always disabled.

Thank you

Like this:

```
$('#btnGeneratePDFMailFormSubmitter').attr('disabled', 'disabled')

            tinyMCE.triggerSave();
            var hallo = $('#GeneratePDFMailFormSubmitter').val();
            if ($.trim(hallo.val) != "") {
                alert(hallo);
                $('#btnGeneratePDFMailFormSubmitter').removeAttr('disabled');//  .attr("disabled", true);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, because at the end of your script, you always disable the button even `if($.trim(hallo.val) != '')`.

Try removing the last  `$('#btnGeneratePDFMailFormSubmitter').attr('disabled', 'disabled');`